# Laravel 5.4 usage of "Storage::putFile"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am working with Laravel 5.4 and want to upload a file (let's call it "lorem.ext") to the storage directory (storage/app/) "path/to/file" with a unique file name.

For that I want to use Storage::putFile (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#storing-files) which not only stores my file, but also automatically creates a unique file name.

The documentation says to use such:

```
Storage::putFile('uploadedFile', new File('/path/to/file'));
```

Using this, I will get the error

```
FileNotFoundException in File.php line 37: The file "/path/to/file" does not exist
```

My further thoughts:

I honestly do not know exactly what the signature means and never found a working example from putFile in the web. In the documentation it is not described and looking closer (https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.html#method_putFile) there is no information, as well.

What I think it means:

The first parameter "uploadedFile" (or as https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#storing-files calls it: "photos") will automatically get the file via the ID from the form in the view:

```
<input type="file" id="uploadedFile" name="uploadedFile">
```

and there is no need anymore to load it via

```
request()->file('uploadedFile')
```

The second parameter "new File('/path/to/file')" (or as https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#storing-files calls it: "new File('/path/to/photo')") will specify the path in the **target** storage directory on the server without the file name:

```
.../storage/app/path/to/file/formerLoremNowUniqueFileName.ext
```

So complete example where I can upload my lorem.ext and it will get stored on  .../storage/app/path/to/file/formerLoremNowUniqueFileName.ext (which does not work):

View:

```
<form method="POST" action="URL/TO/STORE" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="file" id="uploadedFile" name="uploadedFile">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function store() {
    return Storage::putFile('uploadedFile',  new File('/path/to/file'));
}
```

Can anybody

1. describe the signature of "putFile" so that I get it? ;-)
2. tell me why my example is wrong and why I do get this FileNotFoundException?

Thank you!

Comment: Solved it: The first parameter 'uploadedFile' specifies the target file name - e.g. ".../storage/app/uploadedFile/formerLoremNowUniqueFileName.ext". I can change this to e.g. 'path/to/uploadedFile' which will now change the target directory to ".../storage/app/path/to/uploadedFile/formerLoremNowUniqueFileName.ext". The second parameter specifies the file which wants to be uploaded. Normally you get this via request()->file('uploadedFile'). So the solution for my question/example would be "return Storage::putFile('/path/to/file',  request()->file('uploadedFile'));"

Answer (score 4):

First argument passed to `putFile` is the new file location. Example: `/path/to/new/file/`

The second argument is a `File` or `UploadedFile` instance. This can come from `request()->file('uploadedFile')`.

Thus your controller should read

```
public function store() {
    return Storage::putFile(
               storage_path('uploads'),
               request()->file('uploadedFile')
           );
}
```

A generated hash will be used for the file name.

#### Reference:

- [filesystem->putFile()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L133)

Comment: Can you provide a working example without specifying the file name? I want that Laravel creates a unique file name, without me specifying that. Quote from the docs "Note that we only specified a directory name, not a file name. By default, the putFile method will generate a unique ID to serve as the file name."

Comment: Answer to my request: Just leave "/newFile.png" out. So the first parameter only specifies the folder ("uploads") - not the file name. Which means: return Storage::putFile(storage_path('uploads'),  request()->file('uploadedFile'));

Comment: FIY : request()->file("uploadedFile") return an instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile (nice)
but  request()->files->get("uploadedFile") return an instance of  Symfony/UploadedFile, which is not compatible with Storage::putFile !

Comment: Documentation shows `putFile()` has a third argument for 'options' - what options would these be?